# why ng-change function does not fire in my example

Tags: angularjs

I found some article explaining why ng-change may not fire in a repeat, but I think I tried everything I can do and my ng-change is still not firing.

I made a demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rNwnOh8METtgVrSpj1Eu?p=preview)

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="select" name="names" 
ng-change="$parent.$parent.$parent.noSelected(select)">
```

I included a model and tried various $parent.$parent but still it wasn't firing.

Can someone tell me what went wrong with my example?

Comment: does it work if you put `ng-change="alert(1)"` ?

Comment: from your demo, if I change `ng-change` to `onchange` it seems to work

Comment: you shouldn't do that, as onchange is not angular, it won't use scope here.

Comment: oops, you're right :)

Answer (score 0):

The radio button code you have listed is in a template, that is being consumed by a directive. That directive does not have access to your controller scope, as the scope is isolated deliberately.

You need to look thoroughly at the smart-table documentation to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: but if I replace the radio button to checkboxes, they do work with ng-click?

Comment: worked it out, it has nothing to do with scope, instead, I need to define model properly.

Comment: Please update your post or answer to reflect your solution